# Pointer to Python classes and methods

Tags: python, pointers

I would like to have a function pointer dictionary which points to different class methods. What is the best method of doing it?

```
class A():
    command_map = {
       "call func1 of object1":  ("1", func1)
       "call func1 of object2":  ("2", func1)
    }
    def __init__(self, object1, object2):
        self.O1 = object1
        self.O2 = object2
    def call(self, cmd):
        t = self.command_map[cmd]
        target = t[0]
        func = t[1]
        if target == "1":
            resp = self.O1.func()
        elif target == "2":
            resp = self.O2.func()
        else:
            self._logger.warn("Unknown target %r\n" % target)
```

In this case eclipse highlights the func variable saying that it is unused. So how would you proceed? I want to call funca() of objecta or funcb() of objectb dependent on some input values.

Is there a way that self.O1 could be put into "command-map"?

Comment: I think you're looking for `getattr`, but I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `command_map` to hold the function names instead of the actual 'pointers'.

```
command_map = {
    'call func1 of object1': ('1', 'func1'),
    'call func1 of object2': ('2', 'func1'),
}
```

Then you can define your `call` method like this:

```
def call(self, cmd):
    t = A.command_map[cmd]  # command_map is a class attribute, not an instance attribute
    if t[0] == '1':
        o = self.O1
    elif:
        o = self.O2
    else:
        self._logger.warn("Unknown target %r\n" % target)
        return

    f = getattr(o, t[1])  # get the method
    f()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the method name not reference. Then you can retrieve it with `getattr` from the specified object.

```
class A():
    command_map = {
       "call func1 of object1":  ("O1", 'func1_name')
       "call func1 of object2":  ("O2", 'func1_name')
    }

    def __init__(self, object1, object2):
        self.O1 = object1
        self.O2 = object2

    def call(self, cmd):
        target_name, method_name = self.command_map[cmd]

        target_object = getattr(self, target_name, None)
        if target_object is not None:
            method = getattr(target_object, method_name, None)
            if method is not None and callable(method):
                return method()
        else:
            self._logger.warn("Unknown target %r\n" % target)
```

Comment: I'm glad. Could you please approve the answer in that case? Thx.